# How to store nodes of a list into shared memory

Tags: c, pipe, fork, shared-memory

I am trying to make many clients communicate with each other via many terminals.I have forks inside my program and I create pipes so the clients can read/write from/to other clients.Because I create many processes I need shared memory to store some infos and in particular i want to store nodes that are created from each kid.How can I do this?

This is my struct:

```
typedef struct client{
    char *numofclient;
    struct client *nextclient;
}client;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before forking anything create a shared memory area using mmap. Read the man page and use the shared flags. If on Windows it's different so look up VirtualAlloc and of course you can't fork.

You'll need a memory allocator for your shared memory. That can be super easy: just increment a char pointer for an allocation and never free anything. Or it can be as complex as you want. You may be able to find a library online.

If you need a mutex create one in the shared memory area and be sure to use the flags for a shared mutex.

Since you are forking you can use pointers because the shared memory will remain mapped in place in each process copy. Otherwise you'd need to use offsets from the map start.

Comment: But how will I create and store the new nodes so there is a full list inside the shared memory.Malloc is not an option I think.

Comment: @MichalisAndroulakis: Yes you need your own malloc for the shared memory. Write your own function to take sizes and return pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the systemV shared memory using shmget, read man pages.
You can decide an upper limit of how many Process are going to be created and provide that much size accordingly to shmget.
So, whenever you child process wants to store list it can just attach to the shared memory and append its data in shared memory.

Comment: Yeah that's what i am doing but i am struggling to create and store the nodes inside the shared memory this is what i am doing:



    key_t key=ftok("shmemory",1024);
    int shmid=shmget(key,9*sizeof(client),IPC_CREAT|0660);
    if(shmid<0){
        printf("Couldnt allocate the shared memory\n");
        return 0;
    }
    char *shared;
    shared=(char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);